# Fetch Map<String,CustomData> from IBatis

Tags: java, ibatis

I am creating an ibatis quesry that its result should be :

```
Map<String,CustomData>
```

My ibatis query:

```
<resultMap id="dataMap" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <result property="key" column="UUID"/>
    <result property="value" resultMap ="customData"/>
</resultMap>

<resultMap id="customData" class="com.model.CustomData">
    <result property="x" column="X_COL"/>

</resultMap>

<select id="fetchData"
        resultClass="java.util.HashMap"
        parameterClass="java.util.Map">
   SELECT
    UUID AS UUID,
    (CASE
    WHEN SOME_DATA IS NOT NULL THEN  'TRUE'         
    END) AS X_COL
    FROM TABLE
 </select>
```

CustomData is a java class:

```
public class CustomData{
 private String x;

//Getters & Setters

}
```

I expect to get the following on the Java:

```
Map<String,CustomData>
```

However I get the following:

```
Map<String,String>
```

Any ideas !

Comment: Could you provide the code that executes your request and retrieves the Map object?

Comment: Map<String, CustomData> result=
      (Map<String,CustomData>)getSqlMapClientTemplate().queryForObject("namespace" + ".fetchData");

Comment: Kindly find my updated code at my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try to replace the `resultClass` attribute in your `select` tag by a `resultMap` with a `"dataMap"` value like this :

```
<select id="fetchData"
    resultMap="dataMap"
    parameterClass="java.util.Map">
<!-- your query -->
</select>
```

In your case the `queryForList` method try to instanciate a `java.util.HashMap` instead of this, it should use the `dataMap` mapping you defined above.

Comment: I get the following exception:Caused by: com.ibatis.common.jdbc.exception.NestedSQLException:   
--- The error occurred in /sqlmap/ibatisData.xml.  
--- The error occurred while applying a result map.  
--- Check the namespace.dataMap.  
--- Check the result mapping for the 'value' property.  
--- Cause: com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapException: There is no result map named customData in this SqlMap.

Comment: I've solved my issue by:<resultMap id="dataMap" class="java.util.HashMap">
    <result property="key" column="UUID"/>
    <result property="value" resultMap ="namespace.customData"/>
</resultMap>

Comment: I've just added the sql namespace before the result map I refer.

Comment: Thanks zoom for your assistance.